# How to understand the TCP option field I received on my PIC18?

Tags: tcp, header, network-programming, pic18

[image]My goal is to exchange packets between my PIC18F67j60 microcontroller (it has a Ethernet module) and my host computer.
I programmed the PIC18F using MPLABX IDE (C language, pickit3) and on the computer side, I programmed a simple application on CODE::BLOCKS (C language). The application running on my computer works (I tested it). The goal is to establish a TCP communication between the PIC18 and the computer (I know TCP is not that good for embedded devices like microcontrollers cause it takes memory space).
I already managed to establish a UDP communication and I could send and receive any data from both sides.
The issue takes place with TCP communication. The issue is the following : my computer sends a TCP PDU to my microcontroller (to start a connection process, so sets SYN Flag) and my micontroller receives it. Then I decided to display on a screen(using UART) the data received by the microcontroller.
I finally noticed I'm getting a TCP option field added to the TCP "regular" header (in this TCP regular header, the OFFSET byte is "0x**8**0", which means the whole TCP header is **8** * 4 bytes = 32 bytes long or 256 bits long if you want, also 32 = 20 + 12, it means I have 12 more bytes in addition to TCP 20 regular bytes).
The last byte of the TCP Header is the "Urgent Pointer" and right after begins the TCP option that is : TCP option field = " 02 04 05 B4 01 03 03 08 01 01 04 02"
What does this option field means ? I understand that "02 04 05 B4" is for MSS field, but then I'm clueless, I dont understand what the other bytes represent... Any help please ?
Thank you for the help provided.

Comment: Did you try to capture and examine the packet in Wireshark? It displays all know TCP options in human-readable form. If you want to parse them manually read about TCP options in Wikipedia TCP. E.g. after MSS there is 01 which is NOP, then 03 03 is Window Scale.

Comment: Hi yeah thank you, I finally didnt pay attention to the options and everything seems to work. The issue of communication had to do with the right calculation of the TCP Checksum based on the TCP Pseudo Header which I thought didnt have much importance since we dont put it into our frame. Right now  I have another issue that I am facing. I try to exchange http data. To do so, in Firefox I'm typing : @IP + Port number to request my microcontroller (acting as a server). I follow the exchanges on Wireshark. So the first step of connection (3-way handshake) is made correctly. Then I can read the

Comment: http request on Wireshark and on my microcontroller receives correctly the request : "GET HTTP/1.1 ..." . Then my microcontroller responds to Firefox (through the Ethernet cable) : " HTTP/1.1 200 OK ..." and I can see it on Wireshark that detects perfectly the http data sent from my microcontroller and even indicates that the frame sent by my microcontroller is http type. But Firefox cant display (or dont want to) on a page the data sent by my microntroller and keeps on sending TCP Keep Alive request, as if Firefox received the http data but doesnt want to display it or cant display it and

Comment: thus  sends TCP Keep Alive request

Comment: For HTTP debugging I can suggest you to right-click the TCP packet in Wireshark and select Follow TCP - this will gives you a full text flow of your HTTP conversation. You can then copy the text sent by PIC from Wireshark into a file with htm extension and try to open it in a browser or simply check you have a valid HTTP text.

Answer (score 0):

TCP option field = " 02 04 05 B4 01 03 03 08 01 01 04 02", represents some of the fields appearing in TCP option field with their order.
Atleast, the tcp option values found through pyshark packet analyzer, represents encoding for some values:
MSS    -    02:04:05:b4,
NOP    -    01,
Window Scale   -   03:03:08 or 03:03:02,
SACK perm  -  04:02.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).